# iOS swift, retrieving and deleting specific objects from JSON array Parse.com

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

How to query and delete in parse.com when we have a JSON data?

I have a JSON array (as below) stored in Parse.com database under the database key "JSONArray" and parse class "Test". Now I want to delete all the items which contains a specific companyName.

For ex: I want to delete everything that is related to the companyName "james". i.e. index 1 of the the JSON below.

```
 (
    {
    amount = "20.8";
    companyName = valentino;
    optionalNoteText = "This is test 1 ";
    sPreferenceStatus =         (
                    (
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
        )
    );
},
    {
    amount = "52";
    companyName = james;
    optionalNoteText = "This is test 2";
    sPreferenceStatus =         (
                    (
            0,
            1,
            0,
            1,
            0
        )
    );
},
    {
    amount = "10.4";
    companyName = nikki;
    optionalNoteText = “This is test 3”;
    sPreferenceStatus =         (
                    (
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            0
        )
    );
},
    {
    amount = "9.35";
    companyName = jason;
    optionalNoteText = “Test is test 4;
    sPreferenceStatus =         (
                    (
            1,
            0,
            0,
            1,
            0
        )
    );
},
    {
    amount = "8.32";
    companyName = vicky;
    optionalNoteText = "This is test 5";
    sPreferenceStatus =         (
                    (
            0,
            1,
            1,
            0,
            0
        )
    );
}



var findreceivedPostData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Test")
    findreceivedPostData.orderByDescending("createdAt")
```

// This is how we usually filter, in this case its just current user in anArray = ["valentino", "jason", "james", "nikki"].

```
 findreceivedPostData.whereKey("anArray", containedIn: ["\(PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)"])
```

Anyone knows how to work with JSON?

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing JSON data as a string then you need to download the container object, modify the JSON string and then save the container. Or, write a cloud code function to do the same. It isn't really efficient to store data as text like that, you should really model it as pointers/relationships and classes.